# Unit testing a method that checks if the argument equals a certain value?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

I have a method that checks if the argument equals a certain value. Let's assume it checks if the value equals 25.

```
public bool CheckIs25(int input)
{
   return input==25;
}
```

First I wrote a unit test to check if the input is 25 the output must be true (using Xunit):

```
[Fact]
public void CheckIs25_WhenIs25_MustReturnTrue()
{
   var result = testee.CheckIs25(25);

   Assert.True(result)
}
```

Now, how can I test that if the input is NOT 25 the output must be false? I could use a couple of numbers which are not 25 and check if the output is false:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(0)]
[InlineData(24)]
[InlineData(26)]
public void CheckIs25_WhenNot25_MustReturnFalse(int input)
{
   var result = testee.CheckIs25(input);

   Assert.False(result);
}
```

There are a huge number of possible input values, and I can not test all of them.
So I can not test if the output is really only true when the input is 25.
If someone mistakenly changed the method like so:

```
public bool CheckIs25(int input)
{
   return input==25||input==12345;
}
```

Now the method also returns true if the input is 12345.
My unit tests would not fail and the faulty change would not be noticed.

I thought if someone makes a change which alters the behavior of the method, then there must be a failing unit test. This is not the case here.
Could I change my method or the unit tests in any way that a bad change to the code would be result in a failing test?
Or is my notion of unit testing wrong?

Comment: You have two options: *exhaustive* test (all 4 billions from `int.MinValue` up to `int.MaxValue`) which is *slow* or skip some values, and check few rteasonable values only (`24`, `26`, `0`, `-1`, `int.MinValue`, `int.MaxValue`); but in this case a well informed developer (adversary) can put `return input == 25 || input == omittedValue;`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko what do you mean by "but in this case a well informed developer (adversary) can put `return input == 25 || input == omittedValue;`"?

Comment: if you don't test some value (let it be `omittedValue`), say, you don't expect something wrong with `-19248213` since you've checked for `-1`, `int.MinValue`, `-123` and so you don't want to test for it, then a developer (adversary is a better name here) can change `CheckIs25` adding `|| input == -19248213`. You can run test with some random values in order to have non-zero (but small) probability to detect such cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally an epistemological question: *How do you know that a System Under Test works?*

Unless a system is trivial, you can't *prove* that it works exclusively through testing. As Dmitry Bychenko writes in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75810862/126014#comment133728452_75810862), with the particular example in the OP, you *could* exhaust the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of `CheckIs25`, which is around 4 billion values.

If, however, you change the example from an `int` to a `string`, even that option is off the table, as there are (theoretically) infinitely many strings.

Scott Wlaschin covered that problem many years ago in an article called [The Enterprise Developer from Hell](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing/), in which he describes how property-based testing might help.

With property-based testing, you write code that instructs a framework to generate randomized test values. You can then ask the framework to run, say, 1,000 tests. But even if you run a million test cases, what are the odds that one of those million random test cases hits exactly `-738_651_563`, assuming that this is the extra value left by a malicious developer?

The chance isn't that big (around 0.025 %, as far as I can tell), and it becomes even smaller (effectively zero) if you deal with `string` rather than `int`.

As far as I'm aware, automated tests can't guarantee that a non-trivial System Under Test works for *any* input.

IIRC, this is reminiscent of the problem outlined in a paper by Hamlet & Ross titled *Partition Testing Does Not Inspire Confidence*, to which I wrote [a response](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/06/28/property-based-testing-is-not-the-same-as-partition-testing) in 2021.

Other options for preventing errors like this include **code reviews**. That's how I would deal with such a problem, should I identify the need.

Comment: Could we generalize like this?: Proving the intended behavior of functions by unit testing is impossible for functions with an infinite domain. It is hard for functions with a large domain and it is easy for functions with a small domain. Can we conclude that you should always try to keep the domain of a function as small as possible in order to facilitate testing?

Comment: @Patb Thinking explicitly about preconditions is usually a good idea.